What is the purpose of SW1 in the schematic for a battery gauage IC
Does anyone know what the purpose of SW1 is?
The schematic says LED Display but I do not see how this is used for the LED display. The datasheet is found here.


According to the datasheet for this device:

(Picture is a snippet from aforementioned datasheet)
So when you hold down the switch after a particular amount of time, it will change the state of this bit on this particular configuration register to clear.

The switch among other things connects the regulated 2.5V to the VEN pin. This will cause the chip, depending on the configuration, to display using the LEDs.
From the data sheet.

Single LED mode—Upon detecting an A/D value representing 2.5 V on the VEN pin, Single LED mode will toggle the LED as duty cycle on within a period of 1 s where each 1% of RSOC is a 7.8125-ms high time. So, for example, 10% RSOC or SOH will have the LED on for 78.1 ms and off for 921.9 ms. 90% RSOC or SOH will have the LED on for 703.125 ms and off for 296.875 ms. Any value > 90% will display as 90%. Four-LED mode—Upon detecting an A/D value representing 2.5 V on the VEN pin,
Four-LED mode will display the RSOC or SOH by driving pins RC2(LED1), RC0(LED2), RA1(LED3),RA2(LED4) in a proportional manner where each LED represents 25% of the remaining state-of-charge. For example, if RSOC or SOH = 67%, three LEDs will be illuminated.
External LED mode—Upon detecting an A/D value representing 2.5 V on the VEN pin, External LED mode will transmit the RSOC into an SN74HC164 (for 2–8 LEDs) or two SN74HC164 devices (for 9–16 LEDs) using a bit-banged approach with RC2 as Clock and RC0 as Data (see Figure 8-4). LEDs will be lit for a number of seconds as defined in a data flash parameter. Refer to the SN54HC164, SN74HC164 8-Bit Parallel-Out Serial Shift Registers Data Sheet (SCLS115E) for details on these devices.


That's the schematic for the eval board:

Like most eval boards, there are lots of options to choose from with jumper settings so you can try out all the features of the chip.
From the chip's datasheet, you can read about all the various LED display options in section 7.2.12 and some of the implementations are shown in section 8.1. The LED display is driven through pins P1-P4 and the display is activated when the button is pressed and applies 2.5V from the REG25 pin to VEN (the symbol looks weird because someone mirrored it and didn't catch it before releasing the schematic).
Q4 and all the stuff in the upper left part of the schematic are for accommodating different battery voltages via jumpers which you will probably not need in your design (just pick one).
